Googletest installed using homebrew not compatible with arm64
I am trying to install the package ALPSCore on my macOS. I have all the dependencies installed. When I run make, I get the following error:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_mpi_utils_env.cpp in mpi_utils_env.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [utilities/test/mpi_utils_env] Error 1
make[1]: *** [utilities/test/CMakeFiles/mpi_utils_env.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

I checked that GoogleTest has the latest version 1.15.2. It is installed using homebrew.
I have also made sure that CMake is using the homebrew version. My cmakecache.txt file has the following:
// The directory containing a CMake configuration file for GTest.
GTest_DIR:PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib/cmake/GTest

So, I am not sure what is causing the problem.
